# C++11 or newer: most succinct idiom for high resolution timing?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

My goal is to get a number of seconds, in a `double`, holding the amount of time taken by some functions.

The following code works but the clock period verbosity is absurd.

First, I would have guessed that the duration<> would be in units of "1" but since the `now()` is in `ratio<1,1000000000>` duration is too, am I correct?

I have trouble understanding why `ratio` wouldn't have an implicit conversion operator to `double` for instance; if I just use `chrono::high_resolution_clock::period` by itself in a numerical context I wonder why it doesn't simply do the division for me?

```
auto timepointBegin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// do something worth timing

auto timepointEnd  = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

chrono::duration<double> dur = timepointEnd - timepointBegin;

printf( "Total test time: %f sec", dur.count() *
          chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num /
          chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den );
```

I read that `std::chrono::seconds` is basically `typedef duration <long,ratio<1,1>>` but using that to replace the type of `dur` below gives the error of `tstopMT.cxx:67:38: error: conversion from 'duration<[...],ratio<[...],1000000000>>' to non-scalar type 'duration<[...],ratio<[...],1>>' requested`
.  Maybe my eyes are failing me but those look like convertible types?  Also I think that'd be a disaster as it stores seconds in an int, right?

So I tried making the type `chrono::duration<double,ratio<1,1>>` instead but also no joy; it's not adjusting for the fact that now() is returning nanoseconds.  Why not?

Comment: I get the feeling that you're overlooking [`duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

Comment: I saw it but I can't find a succinct idiom to use it in?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a `double`-based duration with the same units as `high_resolution_clock` (nanoseconds in your case).  If that is correct, here is how you can do it:

```
chrono::duration<double, nano> dur = timepointEnd - timepointBegin;
```

or:

```
chrono::duration<double, chrono::high_resolution_clock::period> dur = 
    timepointEnd - timepointBegin;
```

[Here is a video tutorial on `<chrono>`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M) that I recommend.  It will cost you an hour.

Comment: Thx Howard, but I'm basically wanting a double with seconds.  Can you suggest a succinct and common idiom for doing so?  Also what is the difference between passing in chrono::high_resolution_clock and chrono::high_resolution_clock::period?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the duration code is fine.  The problem was that I wasn't actually setting the begin time, so it was calculating the number of seconds since the epoch: currently 1585905624.

I knew (or assumed, or it seemed plausible, I forget) that `high_resolution_clock` would return nanoseconds.  Therefore, it seemed reasonable that `timepointEnd - timepointBegin` would return nanoseconds.

I thought all this complexity with `ratio` would auto-convert those nanoseconds to seconds for me when I assigned the timepoint difference to variable `chrono::duration<double> dur`.  Yet when I printed `dur` it seemed to hold a plausible number of nanoseconds: 1585905624, for my task, which seemed like about 1.5 seconds or so!

Printing out the various values in a debugger made the issue clear.  First I saw to my surprise that `timepointEnd - timepointBegin` *was* 1,000,000,000x bigger than `dur`.  Hmmm, seems like a conversion is being done???  I was still too stupid to pick up this clue, so I printed out `timestampBegin` just to see if it held some idea of nanoseconds or what.  And bingo: 0.

I didn't use the debugger at first because "it was obvious" that the source of my bad result was that I didn't understand how `duration` should be used, not that I wasn't even timing my problem.